# Linux - grep -e works when invoke the script.sh from command but fails when the script.sh is called from crontab

Tags: linux

I tested the below script.sh file. it works when I call from command prompt:

```
#!/bin/ksh

export file="test.txt" 
export dir=$HOME       
export exe_env="test"         
export batch="1"
echo "info: `date` :Environment: ""$exe_env"
echo "info: inputfile: ""$dir/$file"

if [ -f $dir/$file ] ; then             # check if input file exists
        job_list=($( grep -e ':'"$batch"'$' "${dir}/${file}" ))
        for job in "${job_list[@]}"
        do      
            echo ${job}
        done
fi
```

But when I run from crontab as:

```
SHELL=/bin/ksh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=
HOME=/
* * * * * script.sh >> nohup_1.out 2>&1
```

I get the error -

> syntax error at line 11 : `(' unexpected

I tried using double brase. Didn't solve. Any help.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Tried the below line: #!/bin/ksh

export batch=1
export file="/usr/file1.txt"
job_list=( $(grep -e ':'"$batch"'$' $file ) )
for job in "${job_list[@]}"
do
 echo "$job"
done

Comment: It suggest to use read -A. Can't this be directly read from file and split to array?

Comment: changed to  while read line; do job=`echo "$line" | grep -e ':'"$batch"'$' `done < file

Answer (score 0):

When you run tasks from cron, there is usually a small set of environment variables defined.
$HOME is probably missed. Try to run the script using absolute path to the file or command.

Comment: It doesn't help. job_list=( $(grep -e ':1$' "/usr/user1/test.txt") )

Comment: /usr/user1/test.txt has /user/file1:1 --> this line should be picked and placed in an array

Comment: Not sure what data are you trying to get from the file, assuming it has a line is like this: /user/file1:1

Comment: I trying to get all the lines that ends with :1 and place it into array. For ex.  /user/file1:1\n/user/file1:2\n/user/file2:1